# Cannot call DLL function

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have been trying to call a DLL that simply displays a MessageBox. I am running into issues where the loader will not locate the function. When the program is running, nothing happens. Tried using user32.dll which I know works for sure. Everything went fine with the SwapMouseButton function. I have defined my imports and exports. Perhaps they were not done properly? Were my calling conversions wrong?

**Here are my imports and exports:**

```
#ifndef INDLL_H
#define INDLL_H

#ifdef EXPORTING_DLL
extern __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();
#else
extern __declspec(dllimport) void HelloWorld();
#endif

#endif
```

**Hello World DLL (trying to display MessageBox from DLL loader):**

```
/* Hello World DLL */
#include "stdafx.h"
#define EXPORTING_DLL
#include "sampleDLL.h"
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

void HelloWorld()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hello World"),
        TEXT("In a DLL"), MB_OK);
}
```

**DLL Loader (could have wrong conversions):**

```
/* DLL Loader */
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef int(__stdcall* f_funci)();

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("PATH\\LoadME.dll");

    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // resolve function
    f_funci functon = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "HelloWorld");
    if (!functon) {
        std::cout << "Function Could Not Be Located" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "returned " << functon() << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Was your library loaded? Add `std::cout` after `LoadLibrary` call to see if it succeeded

Comment: @VladFeinstein yes, the library was loaded properly. Im pretty sure the problem is in my exports.

Comment: if want to use GetProcAddress to load a c++-function you have use its decorated (link-)name or use extern "C" on the function export/import and defintion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DLL function does not have a calling convention specified, so it will use the compiler's default, which is most likely `__cdecl` NOT `__stdcall`. But your EXE is defining `f_funci` to use `__stdcall`. So, even if the function could be found, it likely won't be called correctly.

Double-check the function's *name mangling* in the DLL's exports table. It i likely being exported as `"_HelloWorld"` instead of `"HelloWorld"`. Consider [using a `.DEF` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files?view=msvc-170) when compiling the DLL in order to control how the function is exported.

Also, consider wrapping the function's declaration in `extern "C"` when compiling in C++.